# How do you handle time unit constants (second, minute, etc)?

Tags: javascript, time, globals

I've been writing a lot of time related code recently, and in various files, I always end up re-defining things like

`var SECOND = 1000;
 var MINUTE = 60 * SECOND;`

This gets frustrating quickly. So I'm considering two possibilities:

1. Getting rid of the constants and instead letting things be inferred from code like `60 * 1000`

   - I dislike this option because it's not as human readable
2. Attaching the constants to a global so they only have to be written in one place

   - I think this is the best way to go, but I'm unsure about the potential consequences of this
3. I could use a package and import from it

   - This has the same problem that I'm already doing, which would be defining it everywhere over and over

How do you handle this issue or is it something we have to live with?

Side note 1: I am writing this in JavaScript, which is why globals are an option, but I feel like this might still be applicable to other languages

Side note 2: Specifically for JavaScript, why are these constants not already attached to the global objects `browser`/`globals`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eliminating Magic Numbers: When is it time to say "No"?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56375/eliminating-magic-numbers-when-is-it-time-to-say-no)

Comment: What's wrong with using Javascript Date objects?

Comment: Be careful with using constants for time like this. Not every minute has 60 seconds.

Comment: C# for example has a `TimeSpan` which encapsulates the unit and the value.  For JavaScript, perhaps checkout the moment.js library, which is useful for managing time.

Comment: @ErikEidt I'm using this for things like `setTimeout(someFunction, 10 * SECOND)`, so Date objects won't work for that. Same answer applies to using moment, @Matthew, which I am using for other functionality, but it does not have constants

Comment: @Merlin-they-them- `moment.duration({ seconds: 10 }).asMilliseconds()`

Comment: Zzzbov. Every minute until 2035 will have 60 seconds. And it seems likely that every minute in anyone’s life time from now on will have 60 seconds.

Comment: @gnasher729 I see that there are plans to stop doing leap seconds by 2035, but what about the decade+ before then? Leap seconds are only announced six months in advance, so it seems premature to declare that there won't be any more before 2035. Do you have evidence to justify that claim? Also note that even if future leap seconds are eliminated by 2035, there are still the historical leap seconds to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

I don't handle constants like that if I can avoid it.

Using the specific example of time in JS, I would use a library that handles those unit conversions itself. Instead of `setTimeout(someFunction, 10 * SECOND)`, I would use something akin to `setTimeout(someFunction, moment.duration({ seconds: 10 }).asMilliseconds())`